# Color correcting a frame buffer before output in Metal

Tags: metal

I need to color correct a Metal frame buffer before output. I have a LUT - basically a texture I feed color values to, and it gives me a new color value back.

Right now I'm rendering everything to a temporary texture, setting up a new render command encoder with the frame buffer as an output, and then running a fragment shader that color corrects the temporary frame buffer into the frame buffer.

The thing I'm not liking is on a 5k display this color correction can take 300ms. When I'm aiming for 60 fps or 120 fps rates - thats somewhat expensive. I've been trying to figure out a better way to do it. Trying to get the color correction to happen under the same render encoder as the actual drawing seems like a possible path. I know setting a new render encoder can cause memory to flush which is not great for performance.

- If I could both read and write to the drawable in the same fragment shader, that could be an option. Fragment shaders support color inputs - but only on Apple Silicon. I still need to support Intel Macs.
- Multiple color attachments seem like another possibility. I could have my temporary buffer and frame buffer both attached to the same render command encoder. And then my shader could just send the corrected pixels straight between the color attachments. The downside is that all my shaders and pipeline states now have to be aware there is a second color attachment - even if they don't care about it - and that is a decent amount of complication and refactoring work. Especially because the color correction is not always done in every frame.
- Compute shaders? Compute shaders don't seem like a big win to me. I'd still have to create a new command encoder. But I haven't done much mixing of compute and render encoders.
- Something else? The Metal layer looks like it may be able to do color space correction, but I haven't found a way to make that work for me yet.

Are there any good patterns for color correcting a frame buffer before output in Metal?

Comment: You could try to ubershader it and just color correct at the end of the last fragment shader you are running. This might save you a round trip on Intel GPUs. On Apple Silicon GPUs you can just use tile dispatches if you don't need the pixels around the one you are color correcting.

Comment: You can just pass the color correcting data/texture to the last fragment shader as a param. Then it can sample from both input texture and LUT and give the final mixed/corrected color back?

Comment: Also why not compute kernels? They are way better of this specific problem, and would run even better since they don't have to run vertex function on geometry. It would be lot efficient. Also you don't have to mix anything with render encoder, you just take out back from last render encoder pass it compute encoder make sure they are in same command buffer/ command queue so that you will sync correct texture (in-order) .

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating a new render pass. Switching to a compute shader would be creating a new pass - unless there is a Metal trick I'm unaware of on Intel. Using the same texture for both input and output is undefined behavior - although I could setup multiple output textures as I hinted. One conclusion I came to is it might be ok to set up a new render pass anyway. I do need to multisample resolve, and it might be better to let the pass end and allow the resolve to happen so less pixels need to be color corrected.